# ¿Cómo puedo validar una serie de cadenas de varias lineas desde un txt en Java?

Tags: java, validación, txt

Tengo una tarea donde debo de validar que las cadenas ingresadas en un txt sean de distintos tipos.

Sólo he podido validar la primera linea. No sé como hacer un ciclo para que me lea linea por linea o separarlas. He intentado usar un `split`, pero no se como seguir leyendo las siguientes lineas.

Lo primero es convertir el cuadro de texto a un `String` para poder leerlo y lo separo con un `split` pero quisiera que cada linea fuera una variable para poder usarla para validarlas.

```
  private void jbtnVariableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling cod x<e here:


         String texto= jTextArea1.getText(); // el textArea se inicializa con un string.
       // se lee linea por linea.
      String[] leerLinea=texto.split("/n");
       
      
      
       int contador =1; 
       int estado=1;  
       int error=0;
       int aceptacion=3;
//iniciamos el contador  int coordenada=estado;
           
         
        while ((contador < texto.length ())&&(estado!=error)){ //compara que el contador la variable sea menor que el largo de la cadena.
             contador ++;
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta usando el enlace 'editar' que está justo bajo tu pregunta